# Infinite scroll for static page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, infinite-scroll

I have coded a paginated comment section,
even if you never used symfony2 its very simple to understand

It just loops through 100 comments and then uses a "next" button for the next comment page to show.

```
{% for comment in pagination %} 
       <div class="comment-container">
           <div class="bubble">
               <div class="cmt-avatar"></div>
               {{ comment.text }}
           </div>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

this method is working perfectly so far.
But it makes the design look terrible, specially with a giant scroll bar on the right side of the page.
What I'd need is a way to make it 'look' like the comment-container is being loaded while the user scrolls.It's obviously just a static page, it just needs to look like its infinite scroll.

**What I've tried so far:**

I found this on this page, it didn't work though, no errors, but does nothing.

```
{% for comment in pagination %} 
   <div class="scrollable-data'">
     <div class="comment-container">
           <div class="bubble">
               <div class="cmt-avatar"></div>
               {{ comment.text }}
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

... script

```
var $doc=$(document);
var $win=$(window);

// hide everything that is out of bound
$('.scrollable-data').filter(function(index){
    return ($(this).scrollTop() > $doc.height());
}).hide();

var DATA_INCREMENT=5;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    // test if at the bottom
    if ($doc.height()-$win.height()-$(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        // show the <DATA_INCREMENT> (5) next hidden data tags
        $('.scrollable-data:hidden:lt('+DATA_INCREMENT+')').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: just to be clear, in your script, in the scroll function, you use `$(window)`, `$win` and `$(this)` and those 3 means the same. You should only use one for better reading.

Comment: You probably have to substitute `<div class=".scrollable-data'">` with `<div class="scrollable-data">` (no dot and no apex)

Comment: oops that was typo, it is actually called class="scrollable-data" on the original project

Comment: I never did this but I'm not sure about your condition `if ($doc.height()-$win.height()-$(this).scrollTop() == 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routine is script intricated.

This is how I would implement this:

A routine that shows only elmenets contained "within the current scrollbar" (sorry, no better words for it):

```
function rescroll(){
          //show all
     $('.scrollable-data').show();
        // hide everything that is out of bound
     $('.scrollable-data').filter(function(index){
         console.log($(this).position().top, $(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop());
         return ($(this).position().top > $(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop());
     }).hide();
}
```

Then call this routine every time the user perform a scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  rescroll();
});
```

Then call also `rescroll()` at the page loading.

#### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5WtTU/

#### Some considerations:

Usually infinite scroll works so that, when the user scrolls 'till a certain comment, then, if he/she scrolls back these *comments* are not hidden again!

So you should save somewhere the maximum of the scroll of a user, and always hide untill this point. In this way you wont re-hide things if the user scrolls up.

Comment: If it works, consider settimg this as accepted answer!